# @Transactional on run() not working

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am using:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager the API of which reads:

> Binds a Hibernate Session from the specified factory to the thread,
>   potentially allowing for one thread-bound Session per factory.

Here is my code under question:

```
@Transactional
    public void insertPerson(Person transientPerson) {
        System.out.println("Current session in insert "+sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()); // Line 1
        personDao.save(transientPerson);
        executeConcurrently();
    }  

    private void executeConcurrently() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Transactional
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("This is a branew thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("In the new thread, session = "+sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()); // Line 2
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

In line 1 I get the session which is obvious. However line 2's execution shows me this error:
This is a branew thread Thread-2

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at edu.sprhib.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl$1.run(PersonServiceImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What I fail to understand is why is this failing? According to my understanding, Spring should create a brand new session and associate it with the ThreadLocal of Thread-2. Is my understanding wrong or the code? I am meanwhile trying to debug the Spring code and my netbeans even after attaching source to the spring-orm jar is not being able to debug inside of it (Please note I am not very good at debugging inside framework's code).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Mustafa

Comment: Two things. First, you are creating the object. It is not managed by Spring and therefore Spring cannot apply transactional behavior. Second, your method is called `executeConcurrently`, but it does its work asynchronously. What's up with that?

Comment: Sorry about the confusing method name and thanks for the other point. I never thought about it and I learn a lesson that you can't think of the whole system as one single thing - you have to remember that things like Spring, Hibernate, JVM co-exist and they are doing their own part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void insertPerson(Person transientPerson) {
        System.out.println("Current session in insert "+sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()); // Line 1
        personDao.save(transientPerson);
        executeConcurrently();
    }  

    private void executeConcurrently() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Transactional
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("This is a branew thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("In the new thread, session = "+sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()); // Line 2
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

By using Propagation.REQUIRED Spring Container handle session you don't need to worry about Session object

if your session object destroyed ,container create new one and provide session if we mention our transaction as a `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED`